# Load custom button symbols (aka icons) into Word 365 Ribbon

Tags: image, button, office365, ribbon

This is regarding the current latest subscription version of Word in Office 365.

I need to make custom images available for buttons in a ribbon customisation.

I have tried the following suggested by various online sources:

1. Load icons (aka images, symbols) into a doc template using (e.g.) RibbonX Editor and save
2. Export my customisation (a new tab with buttons) from the Word ribbon customiser
3. Edit the exported .xml to replace imageMso= attributes with image= attributes referencing the names (without extension) of the icons loaded into the doc template. I have also tried retaining the imageMso attribute.
4. Reload the edited .xml into the Word ribbon customiser

I have tried this with transparent .png and with .jpg files, in both 32px and 64px sizes. It doesn't work -- my ribbon tab just loses all its button symbols.

ETA: Downloaded Visual Studio (free community edition) with VSTO extension, which handles custom button images, so this is no longer an issue for me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.